# User input calculation

Tags: java, input

I have a task to create calculation based on what a users puts in:

```
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = 0;
    System.out.print("write a number: ");
    int k = reader.nextInt();
```

The purpose is that if the user keys in 5 then I should get a print out of
say if they select 5 then it should print out:
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14

and I can't figure out how to do that.

I did import the `import java.util.Scanner`;

Answer (score 0):

am not sure about your questions though.

add this piece code below, if you need to print what ever the user inputs, to 14

```
for(int i = k; i <= 14 ; i++)
{
     System.out.print(i);
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This code may helps to you for implementation,

```
int month;
int day; 
//Please Enter Month and day 
//Hardcoded month=9, day=5;
for(int i = day ; i <= [day+30]; i++)
{
    if(day >30 ) {
    month++;
    day=1;
    }
     System.out.print(i);
}
```